# Smallest positive float64 number in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

How one can get the smallest positive float value in TensorFLow?

In numpy one can use `np.nextafter` and do something like:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.nextafter(0, 1)
4.9406564584124654e-324
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, Tensorflow has `tf.math.nexafter`. See here: [TensorFlow doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/nextafter)

(It's actually unsurprising that TensoFlow is very similar to Numpy here, since the mathematics of Tensorflow are based on those of Numpy, and you can easily use np arrays as data input in tf.)